# How can I replace a specific line of a file in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, text, scripting

I have a file inside the one directory, I want to replace one specific line with another line.

In my case the line is - "password   requisite  pam_pwquality.so"
and I want to make it as

"#password  requisite  pam_pwquality.so".

I tried like this:

```
 cat test1 | while read line
    do
       if grep -q "$str" test1; then
            echo "found"
            sed -i -e "s/${str}/${str1}/g" test1

       fi
```

but it is showing multiple found statements but I am having only one copy of this line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ x='password requisite pam_pwquality.so'
$ sed -i "s/\($x\)/#\1/" file
```

Comment: @priyankaraut if the line is not present, this script will not do anything

Comment: the line is there..... but many are like password requisite pam_pwdqc.so